# How do I reverse a DataFrame back to its Code form?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reverse-engineering

I want to be able to reverse a dataframe back to its code form.

So we know that that this **code form**:

```
dat=pd.DataFrame(dict(Date=['19/11/2012', '20/11/2012', '21/11/2012'],
                    A=[1,3,1],
                    B=[3,2,2],
                    C=[4,3,2],
                    D=[5,2,2],))
```

gives results in a **DataFrame** being created that looks like:

```
+---+------------+---+---+---+---+
|   |    Date    | A | B | C | D |
+---+------------+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 19/11/2012 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | 20/11/2012 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 21/11/2012 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
+---+------------+---+---+---+---+
```

However, is there a way for me to convert a **DataFrame** above back to its **code form**? In the example above, I knew the code to create the DataFrame beforehand, however, in reality I wouldn't have that information.

Comment: you can have multiple ways of "making" a dataframe. So going from output to input is a one to many relationship. So think of it in a different way instead: How can i get the information out of a dataframe so that i can make that same dataframe again? And then just pick one of the many options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [pandas.DataFrame.to_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
>>> dat=pd.DataFrame(dict(Date=['19/11/2012', '20/11/2012', '21/11/2012'],
                    A=[1,3,1],
                    B=[3,2,2],
                    C=[4,3,2],
                    D=[5,2,2],))
>>> dat
         Date  A  B  C  D
0  19/11/2012  1  3  4  5
1  20/11/2012  3  2  3  2
2  21/11/2012  1  2  2  2

>>> dat.to_dict(orient = 'list')
{'Date': ['19/11/2012', '20/11/2012', '21/11/2012'],
 'A': [1, 3, 1],
 'B': [3, 2, 2],
 'C': [4, 3, 2],
 'D': [5, 2, 2]}
```

Comment: It should also be kept in mind that for each possible final state of the `DataFrame` there are inumerous ways in which one could populate and manipulate to reach that final state. Turning the `DataFrame` into a dictionary would only capture that final state.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK Agreed.